# Tomcat OOM Error even when heap-used is well under the limit

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Is there a possibility to get "Out of Memory" errors in Apache Tomcat when Xmx value is too high also?

Why did I ask that?

We have set the Java Heap (Xmx) to 8GB.
    set CATALINA_OPTS= -Xmx8192m
Metaspace is not specified (So that it takes based on the need and there is no chance of the error because of Metaspace).

Still, Tomcat generates OOM errors after sometime and stops responding to user requests.

When we checked JVisualVM for Tomcat process, Heap and Metaspace graphs show well under the limits.
Heap is touching 1.5GB (out of 8GB) and Metaspace is touching 200MB.

I found this link mentioning OOM error when heap is too high.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-crashes-due-to-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error-189433058.html.
I could not find enough resources strengthening this.

Can you please share your thoughts?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace

Comment: Can you share the full runtime parameters? E.g. NewRatio, PermSize etc. As I understand it, if the GC is running too often in trying to reclaim what it think it should be able to reclaim but can't it will throw OOM exception. For example, if you write a bad loop which slowly eat up memory, even those full memory is not reached, it can detect memory leaks and could throw errors.

Comment: Version of Java is important too.

Comment: And remember that trying to create too many threads will also raise an OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Try debugging it with `visualvm` or `jprofiler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other commenters said, to get a better answer, provide a stack trace and other information.

One other typical scenario for a OutOfMemory error is when you try to allocate more memory than available in one go, like when allocating a giant large array. The exception message would simply be 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space', thrown at the location where you allocate the array.